# Creating new column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, startswith

I have a dataframe

```
id_drill depth
454_001   5
456_013   6
454_0078  8.5
455_012   3
00D12_212 4
5G18_356  6
5G15_40   9.1
```

I am trying to add a column `city` to a `pd dataframe`
If the string in the `id_drill` column starts with a key from 2 differents `dict`, then the value added should be the value of the key of that`dict`. But its not working when i'm using the or condition?

```
city_old = {'454': 'NYC', '455':"Montreal" , '456': 'Toronto'}
city_new = {'00D12': 'NYC', '5G15':"Montreal" , '5G18': 'Toronto'}

for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(city_old.items(), city_new.items()):
    try:
        df.loc[(df['id_drill'].str.startswith(k) ==True) or (df['id_drill'].str.startswith(k2) ==True), 'city'] = v2
        
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Here is the result I except :

```
id_drill depth  city
454_001   5     NYC
456_013   6     Toronto
454_0078  8.5   NYC
455_012   3     Montreal
00D12_212 4     NYC
5G18_356  6     Toronto
5G15_40   9.1   Montreal
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First using `dict` unpacking merge the two dictionaries then use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + [`Series.str.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the values from the merged dictionary to the strings in column `id_drill`:

```
m = {**city_old, **city_new}
df['city'] = df['id_drill'].str.split('_').str[0].map(m)
```

Result:

```
    id_drill  depth      city
0    454_001    5.0       NYC
1    456_013    6.0   Toronto
2   454_0078    8.5       NYC
3    455_012    3.0  Montreal
4  00D12_212    4.0       NYC
5   5G18_356    6.0   Toronto
6    5G15_40    9.1  Montreal
```